# Scrolling image in html5up theme "Alpha"

Tags: css

I have site based on [Alpha theme from html5up](http://html5up.net/alpha) and I need the main image (banner) to scroll with page. I found some articles about scrolling image, but css is so big and I can't find what I mus't edit.

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should give fixed position to your banner.

```
#banner{ 
       position: fixed;
       }
```

Comment: This destroy whole layout. (You can change code at the url which I post)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the css file "style.css"

change the first property in #banner to

```
background-attachment:scroll,scroll;
```

Comment: This does nothing. (You can change code at the url which I post)

Comment: Nopes, i am pretty sure, i tried it again and it worked.

Comment: Initially it is background-attachment:scroll,fixed;  change it to background-attachment:scroll,scroll;

Comment: I made test subdomain for it. [link](http://alpha.lukasholeczy.eu/) There is a clear version of Alpha template with your change in code. It didn't worked for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I looked into Inspect element and the line is crossed out. I tried !important, but it didn't worked.